# Python Script to disconnect a particular Wi-Fi network

Tags: python, windows, wifi

Lemme explain the situation first,

My work laptop is configured to connect to my Office Wi-Fi connect whenever it's in the vicinity. I have a problem with that. I connect to my Client Network using LAN and work using Putty in Linux machines in Client network. If the Wi-Fi network is connected, then my Putty disconnects and it leaves me with problems - unsaved files, losing output of crucial commands / programs,etc.

So i'm looking for a way to disconnect the Wi-Fi whenever it connects within a fraction of a second.

I know for the Wi-Fi connectivity, there will be a event triggered in OS side, so i am looking for a way to capture that event and check Wi-Fi network name and disconnect it immediately.

How do i do that using Python ?

Comment: If you have the permission to manage wireless network, why don't you just "forget" your work office WiFi connection in network and sharing center?

Comment: Nope, i don't have permission to manage this Particular Office Wi-Fi network.